# Uncertainty principle for a particle of known momentum

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

For a particle of known momentum we know the wave function. But why is that in that case we have uncertainty in momentum then according to uncertainty principle ∆x∆p>=h/2π? If so then uncertainty in what sort of momentum exactly?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a little unclear. If the momentum is known exactly, the wave is a plane wave, so the position is totally delocalised.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30106/is-there-any-uncertainty-on-the-free-particle-with-a-definite-momentum-vec-p?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The wave-function of particle with know momentum the is just a phase $\psi (x)=e^{ipx}$ and therefore the uncertainty in momentum is vanishing $\Delta^2 p=0$. On the otherhand, since the wave-function is a phase the probability density is constant $|\psi(x)|^2=1$. This means that we have no information about the position of the particle, hence an infinite incertenty. Since momentum is known precisely and position is completely unknown, the uncertainty theorem is satisfied. Note that this case is peculiar because the wave-function can not be normalized (unless you are in a box).